# Can I make my dash app return static responses using curl

Tags: python, curl, plotly-dash

I've defined a multi page Dash app:

app.py:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
...
app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [navbar, nav, dash.page_container]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

page.py:

```
import dash
import json
import yaml
from dash import html, dcc, Input, Output, State, ALL, callback
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from filelock import FileLock

dash.register_page(__name__, order=1, title='️ My page')
...
def layout(**other_unknown_query_strings):
    ....
```

The page handles some resources which the user can reserve or release. However, except the dash GUI in the web browser I would like to be able to reserve and unreserve via `curl` and return a static response such as {"result": "ok"}.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first assumption was bad design.

I solved this by having an external `Flask` driven server handle the resources.